# Why do my android spinners look horrible?

Tags: android, user-interface, spinner

I am using the default theme (dark) and a 2.2 / API level 8 target. When I add a basic spinner to my layouts, they look horrible. The text is very hard to read (gray-on-gray) and the arrow looks funny:

[image: My Spinners]

If I use the light theme, they look fine. If I look at the android API examples their spinners look fine in the default dark theme:

[image: Normal Spinners]

Why are all my spinners ugly and unreadable? What am I doing wrong?

The simplest possible code will display this way:

```
  final Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  list.add("foo");
  list.add("bar");
  mySpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, list));
```

and layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/mySpinner"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"></Spinner>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What item layout are you using?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by 'item layout'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would set the layout_height on the spinner to wrap_content instead of match_parent.  I don't see any code related to setting some of the other options like the adapter, etc so I guess there is some code that is missing.  I'm wondering if the spinner is disabled and why it's grayed out like that.

Ah it could be your background is showing through the control.  Try changing the background color on your LinearLayout see if it's shining through.

Comment: layout_height is set to wrap_content in his question.  Threw me off the first time I read it but the property order is reversed between the layout and the spinner.

Comment: It doesn't matter how I size it (layout_height). It's not disabled as it does show the pop-up and take selections. When I set the main theme in my manifest to Theme.Light, it looks just fine. It's only when using the default theme that it looks like this. You can see the down arrow graphic even looks weird -- not a triangle like it should be.

Comment: You are correct.  I was hoping it was a easy one.  But I can tell that the height of the Spinner is the same size as the text field, and it looks like it's scaled up that what it wants to be.

Comment: changing background color has no effect -- it is opaque.

Comment: For further reference, added code for adapter to question. You can see it's pretty basic.

Comment: The "grey" problem then is the layout you choose when defining what the Adapter will use.  I'd double check and make sure you're using the same layout as the planets.

Comment: Aha, that is the problem. I need to replace the adapter's R.layout.list_item with android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item. My list_item only defines text size and padding, so not sure why it has such a terrible effect on color and arrows but I'll take it!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
mySpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        MyActivity.this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list));
```

Answer (score 1):

http://polyclefsoftware.blogspot.com/2009/06/how-to-change-your-spinner-typeface.html

Try reading this page. It goes over how to customize the text in your Spinner.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the TextView TextColor attribute of the spinner to 0xFF000000 for opaque black.

In your case, you may extend the ArrayAdapter class so that the getView returns a view with a 0xFF000000 TextColor attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue and realized the error was the "context" selected while creating the adapter. I had used "getApplicationContext()" and this was causing the greyed out image.  Once i changed it to the activity context "MainActivity.this" the problem was fixed. Thanks to nz_karl for pointing it out.